# Deploy CXF jax-ws webservice on Websphere 8.5.5.12

Tags: cxf, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy a jax-ws webservice on Websphere 8.5.5.12. I am using CXF as my jax-ws engine. I have gone through the prerequisites and changed the class loader as well as desabled the JaxWs engine in websphere. I have set the property to disable Jax-WS engine in the manifest file of my war file.

My application is a  Spring boot application. I am also using apache camel 2.20.1 and using the cxf end point to consume the messages. 
As a spring boot application my application is working fine.
When I deploy on Websphere my application starts without any issues. But when it intercepts any incoming requests, it throws class not found exception for javax.servlet.WriteListener class. This class is part of the servlet api. It should have been part of the Websphere j2ee library.

Need to know what I did wrong. I don't want to take the shared library route. I have been suggested, that I need to move all my cxf dependencies, into a shared library and set my  class loader for this library. I am not comfortable with this solution.

Comment: Have you considered trying your application inside of WebSphere Liberty instead of in the traditional application server?

Answer (score 3):

`javax.servlet.WriteListener` is a Servlet 3.1 / Java EE7 API.

WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 implements Servlet 3.0 / Java EE6.

You should use either WebSphere Application Server 9.0.0.x or any recent WebSphere Liberty release (which has been versioned differently for quite some time).

(or, remove the 3.1 dependencies from your app if you must run it on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5)